# Comparing means with Scipy: Direction of difference

Tags: python, scipy, statistical-test

I am comparing two columns from two different dataframes. All participants come from the same population/dataset. I want to check whether the average diastolic blood pressure differed across patients and their matched controls. I have uploaded the two dataframes, df_positives and df_controls.

I have the below code:

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_rel
scipy.stats.ttest_rel(df_positives['Average_BP_Diast_Autom'].dropna(), df_controls['Average_BP_Diast_Autom'].dropna())
```

And I get the below result:

```
Ttest_relResult(statistic=2.0892097303753023, pvalue=0.038232699505362)
```

That tells me that there is a significant difference between the two means, but how can I check which mean is greater? Would there be a more convenient test to check that?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured that the direction can be inferred: the second argument (or second value) is the one being subtracted from the first one, so if the difference is a positive number, that means the first mean is greater.

Switching the value places would lead to the same resuls (t and p values), but the sign of the t value will be opposite, that is, if it was a positive value before, it would now be a negative.